# Kendo Grid is not displaying json data webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, webforms, kendo-grid

I'm a new comer to kendo grid, I'm using webmethod to trigger it. With the help of lots of forums, finally I'm able to trigger request to webmethod. The problem is that my method is returning number of records in JSON format. For simplicity, I consider one hardcoded JSON record here is response:

```
{"d":"{\"pk_Picture\":22,\"P_DisplayOrder\":1,\"AltAttribute\":\"Smith\",\"TitleAttribute\":\"Smith\"}"}

<script>
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#productpictures-grid").kendoGrid({
                        height: 200,
                        columns: [
                            { field: "pk_Picture", title: "Picture",  width: "150px" },
                            { field: "P_DisplayOrder", width: "150px" },
                            { field: "AltAttribute", width: "100px" },
                            { field: "TitleAttribute", width: "100px" },
                            { command: "destroy", title: "Delete", width: "110px" }
                        ],
                        pageable: {
                            info: true
                        }, // enable paging
                        //filterable: true, // enable filtering
                        //sortable: true, // enable sorting
                        editable: true, // enable editing
                        //toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"], // specify toolbar commands
                        dataSource: {
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverSorting: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            pageSize: 10,
                            schema: {
                                data: "d.results", // web methods return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }. Specify how to get the result.
                                total: "d.Total",
                                model: { // define the model of the data source. Required for validation and property types.
                                    fields: {
                                        pk_Picture: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                                        P_DisplayOrder: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                                        AltAttribute: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                                        TitleAttribute: { editable: true, type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                           // batch: true, // enable batch editing - changes will be saved when the user clicks the "Save changes" button
                            transport: {
                                create: {
                                    url: "TestPage.aspx/Create", //specify the URL which should create new records. This is the Create method of the Products.asmx service.
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web method to serialize JSON
                                    type: "POST" //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for web methods
                                },
                                read: {
                                    url: "Update.aspx/FillProductDataById", //specify the URL which data should return the records. This is the Read method of the Products.asmx service.
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web method to serialize JSON
                                    type: "POST" //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for web methods
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: "TestPage.aspx/Update", //specify the URL from which should update the records. This is the Update method of the Products.asmx service.
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web method to serialize JSON
                                    type: "POST" //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for web methods
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: "TestPage.aspx/Destroy", //specify the URL which should destroy records. This is the Destroy method of the Products.asmx service.
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web method to serialize JSON
                                    type: "POST" //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for web methods
                                },
                                parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                                    if (data.models) {
                                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                                        return JSON.stringify({ products: data.models });
                                    } else if (operation == "read") {
                                        //Page methods always need values for their parameters
                                        data = $.extend({  ProductIds: $('#Id').val() }, data);
                                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Here is my server method

```
    [WebMethod]
public static string FillProductDataById(string ProductIds)
{
    BLProduct objProduct = new BLProduct();
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { pk_Picture = 22, P_DisplayOrder = 1, AltAttribute = "Smith", TitleAttribute = "Smith" });
    return json;
    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //dt = objProduct.GetProductByProductId(ProductIds);
    //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

it seems the JSON that you return from the server is not array.
JSON data from server to kendo shoud be an array.

For example:

```
[{"pk_Picture":22,"P_DisplayOrder":1,"AltAttribute":"Smith","TitleAttribute":"Smith"},
{{"pk_Picture":33,"P_DisplayOrder":2,"AltAttribute":"Hamed","TitleAttribute":"Hamed"}]
```

so do this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string FillProductDataById(string ProductIds)
{
    BLProduct objProduct = new BLProduct();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = objProduct.GetProductByProductId(ProductIds);
    var dataArray = dt.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataArray);
}
```

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: check answer again.